# Why was Pygmalion retitled to My Fair Lady?

Tags: textual-history, title, george-bernard-shaw, pygmalion-shaw

George Bernard Shaw's play [*Pygmalion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmalion_(play)) has been adapted many times for different media, but most notably as a musical entitled [*My Fair Lady*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Fair_Lady). This musical was so popular that some screen adaptations have used the title "My Fair Lady" instead of the original "Pygmalion".

**Why was the title changed to "My Fair Lady"?** Is there any connection with the nursery rhyme ["London Bridge is Falling Down"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Bridge_Is_Falling_Down) which is often also called "My Fair Lady"?

Comment: Presumably, you're not asking why they avoided Pygmalion as a title, but why they chose My Fair Lady instead of something else? One likely answer comes to mind: focus groups (a.k.a product marketing).

Comment: Is the account in the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Fair_Lady#Background unsatisfactory?  It cites a book by Lerner,  _The Street Where I Live_, which presumably has more details.

Comment: It’s a Hollywood musical, most likely the producers were worried the classical allusion would be lost and/or off-putting for its intended audience.

Comment: Huh, TIL. I always assumed it was a West End musical first.

Comment: @Randal'Thor it was, with Julie Andrews in the starring role. The movie with Audrey Hepburn came later.